# Dynamic URL in PHP not working when passing "&" in href tag

Tags: php

I have the following URL

```
http://localhost:8777/business.php?id=Mobiles and Tablets
```

When I am passing "and" in id it is redirecting me to the desired page but when I am passing

```
http://localhost:8777/business.php?id=Mobiles & Tablets
```

& i.e. ampersand in id it is giving 404 error.

My PHP Code is like this:

```
<a href="business.php?id=<? echo $cat;?>"><? echo $cat;?></a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) in your php code.

```
<a href="business.php?id=<? echo urlencode($cat) ;?>"><? echo $cat;?></a>
```

It will generate link like:

```
http://localhost:8777/business.php?id=Mobiles+%26+Tablets
```

`Space` will be converted to `+`, and `&` will be converted to `%26`

Answer (score 2):

use php [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

> This function is convenient when encoding a string to be used in a query part of a URL, as a convenient way to pass variables to the next page.

And use [urldecode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to decode your encoded argument

> Decodes any %## encoding in the given string. Plus symbols ('+') are decoded to a space character.